# Find a value of $\;\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left ( e- e^{\frac{1}{e}}\uparrow\uparrow n \right )$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, logarithms, laurent-series, power-towers

> Find a value of
> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n\left ( e- e^{\frac{1}{e}}\uparrow\uparrow n \right )$$
> For your information$,\quad\uparrow\uparrow$ is a tetration defined as
> $$a\uparrow\uparrow n:=\underbrace{a^{a^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{a}}}}}}_{n}$$

I think we must use the function $\ln x$ here then use the Laurent series of $\ln x.$ But I couldn't find an extension formula of $\ln e^{\frac{1}{e}}\uparrow\uparrow n,$ I need to the help, thanks a real lot !

Comment: is the $n$ part of what you are taking the limit of?

Comment: @JoshuaWang, it's just a way of thinking, maybe not true.

Comment: Apart from that there is no convention whether $0$ is a natural number , what on earth has that to do with this question ?

Comment: Essentially, I understand this to mean: find $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(e-x_n)$, where $x_1=\alpha$, $x_{n+1}=\alpha^{x_n}$ and $\alpha=e^{1/e}$, is this correct? That limit would be simply $2e$.

Comment: @NoNames, that's a good work.

Comment: I met you again

Comment: @Angelo please do not change `'\lim` to `\lim\limits` in titles. Firstly you are disagreeing with the OP who has repeatedly rolled back your edit. Secondly Displaystyle mathematics uses up more vertical space than is needed in a list of questions. Thirdly its probably better if you don't do it inside the body, when it appears in between a pair of single dollar signs `$...$`

Comment: Firstly I am not changing the contents of titles, but I am just improving its appearance. Secondly, vertical space used is appropriate. Thirdly, to do it inside the body does not generate any problem.

Comment: @Angelo absolutely wrong on all counts

Comment: Evidently I am right on all I wrote.

Comment: The only reason I have not reverted your edit is because it is wrong to continuously bump a post for a minor edit (which is precisely what you have been doing). Please stop making titles use more vertical space than is needed. Regarding using it in the body, It makes line spacing bad.

Comment: @Angelo no, your edit is very minor, the vertical space does not improve the appearance, and it makes the title larger than it should be in relation to other posts. I have said what I wanted to say; have a good day

Comment: My edit just does little changes, but even so the appearance of titles improves.

Comment: I have just reopened your topic for you.

Comment: @Angelo, thank you so much very much.

Comment: I have reopened your topic

Comment: I'm so obliged.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To put that into a more reasonable (though less prone to enthusiastic upvotes) form: We have $x_1=e^{1/e}$ and $x_{n+1}=e^{x_n/e}$, and we're looking for $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,(e-x_n)$. Letting $y_n=1-x_n/e$, some elementary algebra gives $$y_{n+1}=1-e^{-y_n}.$$ The precise value of $y_1$ is not so important, as long as it is positive. Then, $y_n$ is monotone decreasing, and positive, so it must have a limit $y$ satisfying $y=1-e^{-y}$, i.e. we must have $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n=0$. Now some more elementary algebra gives
$$\frac1{y_{n+1}}-\frac1{y_n}=\frac{e^{-y_n}+y_n-1}{y_n\,(1-e^{-y_n})}\to\frac12$$ as $n\to\infty$, and by the   [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n\,y_n}=\frac12.$$ Substituting the definition of $y_n$, we obtain $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,(e-x_n)=2\,e.$$ Convergence is rather poor, the error is $O\left(\frac{\log n}n\right)$.

Comment: How have you obtained that the error is $O\left(\frac{\log n}n\right)$? Please, could you tell me it?

Comment: Nonames, please, could you tell me why the error is $O\left(\frac{\log n}n\right)$ ?